# Azure portal Performance test: Generate load from Brazil South

Tags: azure, azureportal

In the **Azure Portal**, when trying to create a **Performance test** for a web app, I don't see the option "**Generate load from: Brazil South**"

[image: Azure performance test]

Question: how can I do a performance test on my web app if it is in Brazil South?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we only can select one of the 9 web app locations as you see in the list. There is no option of **Brazil South** Azure datacenter there. It's welcome to give feedback and feature requests [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites).

To simulate local conditions and reduce latency, you can select a location closest to your users for generating load.

Also, you can [load test your app in the cloud using Visual Studio and VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/getting-started-with-performance-testing?view=vsts). It will have an option for **Brazil South** location.